# Accessing PostgreSQL service on host from Node app in Docker container

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker

I have a PostgreSQL service running on my host machine (Mac) and I want to connect to it from within my Docker container in my Node app. I know that there's `docker.for.mac.localhost` but first step I wanted to use the straightforward method, which was to pass my host IP address directly into the container. However, that hasn't been working and I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm using the Node `pg` package to connect to my database. Any help would be great, thanks!

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    env_file:
      - .env
    build: .
    command: npm run watch
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASS}@${LOCAL_IP}:5432/${POSTGRES_DB}
      - PGHOSTADDR=${LOCAL_IP}
      - PGPORT=5432
      - PGDATABASE=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - PGUSER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - PGPASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASS}
```

Dockerfile

```
# pull node 9.4 as base
FROM node:9.4.0

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# copy packages.json in
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/app

RUN rm -rf node_modules

# run files
RUN npm install

# copy everything else in
COPY . /usr/src/app

# expoxe port
EXPOSE 8080

# starting task
CMD npm run watch
```

connection.js

```
const { Pool } = require("pg");

const pool = new Pool({
  user: process.env.PGUSER,
  host: process.env.PGHOSTADDR,
  database: process.env.PGDATABASE,
  password: process.env.PGPASSWORD,
  port: process.env.PGPORT
});

export = {
  query: (text: String, params: Object, callback: Function) => {
    console.log(pool);
    return pool.query(text, params, callback);
  }
};
```

Here's the error
[image]

Comment: If you already use docker and even docker-compose, put also the postgresql into a docker container. The official images are easy to use and the docker networking easily connect your container

Comment: What is the output of your failed connection?

Comment: @OkieOth I posted the error I get from the Chrome console - and I'll look into that as well, but I'm also really curious why this isn't working

Answer (score 0):

They are not on the same network I think. From the container, the local IP is the container itself, not your host.
You should try to add the DB on your docker compose, or maybe add a network section.

Comment: Right - within the Docker container I passed in my host's IP address `PGHOSTADDR=${LOCAL_IP}`